# Specifying a Restricted Domain that can Make a Function Convex

Tags: optimization

Define a function  $f : S_1 \to \mathbb R$ by:
$$ f (\vec x) = (x_1 - 2)^2 - (x_2-1)^2 $$
with domain
$$S_1 = \left\{\vec x \in \mathbb R^2  : 0 \le x_1 \le 1, \lvert x_2\rvert \le \frac{x_1}{2}\right\}.$$

Sketch $S_1$.

How do we go about sketching this?

Comment: Try desmos. ${}$

Comment: Triangle with corners $(0,0), (1,1/2), (1, -1/2).$

Comment: @copper.hat how do we do it with this type of domain?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [demos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m69pqxygax) is a great tool. To graph $S_1$, one can start by considering the inequalities separately. First:

$$0\leq x_1\leq 1.$$

This just determines two parallel vertical lines at $x_1=0$ and $x_1=1$ where our area of interest lies:

[image]

Now, if you recall the definition od the absolute value, the second condition that defines $S_1$ is equivalent to:

$$-x_1/2\leq x_2 \leq x_1/2.$$

This gives us two distinct lines between which $S_1$ must lie. They look like:

[image]

If we put these two are together, we get that $S_1$ is defined by the intersection:

[image]

You can find the boundaries of this triangle, right?